# How to route through URL parameter values instead of URL path values in ASP.NET Core 6 Web API?

Tags: asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

On the client side, I can only request a URL address from the Web API, but I need to provide many different logic.

So, my Web API URL is

```
http://exampleDomain.com/ControllerDemo/HubActions?ActionName=（This url in client can't change）
```

When request url is

```
http://exampleDomain.com/ControllerDemo/HubActions?ActionName=ActionA
```

it should be routed to `/ControllerDemo/ActionA`

When request url is

```
http://exampleDomain.com/ControllerDemo/HubActions?ActionName=ActionB
```

it should be routed to `/ControllerDemo/ActionB`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `Program.cs` (`ImplicitUsings`):

Just add custom middleware before `app.UseRouting()`, like this:

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
{
    if (context.Request.Path == "/ControllerDemo/HubActions")
        context.Request.Path = $"/ControllerDemo/{context.Request.Query["ActionName"]}";
    await next(context);
});

app.UseRouting();
```

See [MSDN documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-6.0#aspnet-core-endpoint-definition-1):

> The endpoint, if selected, can be retrieved from the `HttpContext`. Its properties can be inspected. Endpoint objects are immutable and cannot be modified after creation. The most common type of endpoint is a `RouteEndpoint`. `RouteEndpoint` includes information that allows it to be selected by the routing system.